# Filtering dropdownlist values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing simple feature using Entity Framework and asp.net mvc5.

**What I want to get:**

I have database dictionary for the devices manufacturers. 
And on the webpage I have 2 dropdown lists filled with Manufacturers and product names. 
In the perfect way it should filter the "names" dropdownlist to consist only products of the chosen manufacturer.

**My Question:**

Is there any correct and simple way to get this work as I want without using JS or js and filtering where one dropdownlist triggers action is the only solution?

**How I'm reading data from database:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var MList = new List<string>();
        var Query = from d in db.Dictionaries
                       orderby d.DeviceManufacturer
                       select d.DeviceManufacturer;
        MList.AddRange(Query.Distinct());
        var NList = new List<string>();
        Query = from d in db.Dictionaries
                orderby d.DeviceName
                select d.DeviceName;
        NList.AddRange(Query.Distinct());
        ViewBag.Manufacturers = new SelectList(MList);
        ViewBag.Names = new SelectList(NList);
        return View();
    }
```

**How I populate dropdownlists:**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("Manufacturers");

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("Names");
    </div>
```

**My database schema (Code First):**

```
   public class Device
{
    public int DeviceId { get;set; }
    public string DeviceSerialNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(14)]
    public string DeviceUser { get; set; }
    public int DeviceDictionaryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DeviceDictionaryId")]
    public virtual DeviceDictionary DeviceDictionary {get;set;}
    public string Batch { get; set; }
}
 public class DeviceDictionary
{

    public int DeviceDictionaryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DeviceManufacturer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want things to happen client side you have to use JavaScript.

So you are correct in assuming that one way of doing it would be to call an action when something is selected in the first dropdownlist and give the user a "new" page.

Comment: Thanks. But then shouldn't I ask database engine with some Ajax question to get new data? I'm asking because I'm quite new in webdesign.

Comment: You can use the Ajax helpers available, but I'd bite the apple and learn a little JS. It's quite simple to accomplish what you want you can use jQuery which should already be included in your project.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790944/filtering-subsequent-dropdowns-with-jquery